# Parsing XML type file

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

I'm using Java, and I need to get information from one AutomationML file (XML type file). I try to use JAXB to do that but in the end I can't get the information I need.
In AML I have one InstanceHierarchy with 3 InternalElements with some attributes, and I need that attributes values, but using JAXB I get the AttributeName but I can't get its value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CAEXFile caex = null;
    CAEXFile.InstanceHierarchy ih = null;
   try {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CAEXFile.class);
        //JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(generated.CAEXFile.InstanceHierarchy.class);
        Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        CAEXFile aml = (CAEXFile)ums.unmarshal(new File("src\\teste2.aml"));

        System.out.println("ins = " + aml.getInstanceHierarchy().get(0).getInternalElement().get(0).getAttribute().get(0).getName());

  } catch (JAXBException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

The xsd file [XSD (CAEX)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qts00hbvoz2qy0/CAEX_ClassModel_V2.15.xsd?dl=0%22XSD%22) and AML file [AML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq86rr3wy8ha4vd/teste2.aml?dl=0)
Can someone help me using JAXB or give me some directions how to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually avoid JAXB altogether, which can be useful depending on the rest of your code. If you can use Java 8 perhaps [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics) would be a nice & direct solution.

```
XmlDynamic example = new XmlDynamic(xmlStringOrReaderOrInputSourceEtc);

String firstInternalName = example.get("CAEXFile|InstanceHierarchy|InternalElement|@Name").asString();
// TestProduct_1

List<String> allInternalNames = example.get("CAEXFile").children()
    .filter(hasElementName("InstanceHierarchy")) // import static alexh.weak.XmlDynamic.hasElementName;
    .flatMap(Dynamic::children)
    .filter(hasElementName("InternalElement"))
    .map(internalElement -> internalElement.get("@Name").asString())
    .collect(toList());
// [TestProduct_1, TestResource_1, TestProduct_2, TestProduct_3, TestResource_2]
```

It's a single and lightweight extra dependency, ie in maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.alexheretic</groupId>
  <artifactId>dynamics</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved with double unmarshall ;)